# Xamarin HttpClient authorization requesting ALB Cognito endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito

I am working on a mobile app that makes HTTP requests to an API that is protected behind an ALB Cognito configuration.

I have been able to authenticate via SRP Auth with the following code:

```
CognitoUser User = new CognitoUser(
    "email@email.com", 
    Constant.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID, 
    CognitoUserPool, 
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient);

    // Send a login request and wait for the response from Amazon
    AuthFlowResponse response = await User.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
    {
     Password = "password"
    });
```

This successfully logs in with a user defined in a User Pool, and at this point, I have an AccessToken, a Session ID, and a Refresh Token.

I would like to then use the tokens returned to allow my app to make HTTP requests to an API running on an ECS instance that is managed by the ALB authentication flow.

So the API and the mobile app are using two separate client ids under a shared User Pool.

How do I then make requests from the authenticated mobile app to the ALB instance? I do not see a header that should be used from the documentation.

Comment: Do you reffer to this document to test(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancer-getting-started.html)?

Comment: @johnheaven yes, I've got my ALB set up correctly with no issue. I have no problem authenticating web requests from browsers. I'm having an issue finding the best way to authenticate http requests from my Xamarin app, being sent to a web app running on the ALB behind the built in ALB cognito auth flow.

Comment: any luck on this? i'm running into the same issue

Comment: @user7400346 Unfortunately this was long enough ago that I forget what the resolution was. I'm no longer able to access the relevant project...I think we had something misconfigured on how we were interfacing with AWS from the mobile app. Sorry not very helpful :(

Comment: no worries, thank you! have a great day.